# Access to Jenkins using public IP address

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ec2

I've installed Jenkins on my [AWS](http://Amazon%20AWS) Windows system. I am able to access it within a system using http://localhost:8080/, but I can't access it outside the system using the public IP address.

http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/

My [EC2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Elastic_Compute_Cloud) instance is assigned with the public IP address.

I've changed the URL in the Jenkins system configuration too.

How can I access Jenkins from outside the local system? I need the Jenkins' public access URL for linking it with GitHub WebHook.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Usually, there are three things you should check:

1. Local firewall on Windows Server. If it's enabled, does it allow connections on port 8080.
2. Network ACL for the network. Both incoming traffic on TCP port 8080 **and** outcoming traffic on TCP port 8080 should be allowed.
3. Security group for your EC2 **and** your VPC internet gateway (if that exists). Security group should allow incoming TPC traffic on port 8080 for you IP address (or the whole world, e.g. 0.0.0.0/0).

Comment: Yes it looks local firewall is allowing the connection. 

In EC2 the Inbond and  outbond connections are allowing all the traffics. But still i can't reach that URL from outside.

Comment: Yes it looks local firewall is allowing the connection on port 80. [I can able to telnet my local system IP using Port 80]

In EC2 the Inbond and  outbond connections are allowing all the traffics. 

But still i can't reach that URL from outside.

Comment: Still i can't access the jenkins from outside of my local machine, http://ec2-54-224-186-155.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080/

Please suggest answers to fix this issue

Comment: after i created the Inbound rule inside the EC2 instance, now i can able to access the URL.

ControlPanel-->system ans security --> Advance --. Allow Port 8080 [new rule]

Answer (score 1):

after i created the Inbound rule inside the EC2 instance, now i can able to access the URL. ControlPanel-->system ans security --> Advance --. Allow Port 8080 [new rule]

Answer (score 1):

The answer of Sergey Kovalev is correct but i think it will be more safe to allow incoming TCP traffic for only Github IP range from this link https://help.github.com/articles/what-ip-addresses-does-github-use-that-i-should-whitelist/.
I want to put it as comment under his answer but I dont't have enough reputation. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

You have to add port 8080 to security groups.

https://d1.awsstatic.com/Projects/P5505030/aws-project_Jenkins-build-server.pdf

step 1: Go to Security Groups and select your security group

step 2: click on inbound roles then click on Edit inbound rules button

step 3: Click Add Rule, and then choose Custom TCP Rule from the Type list. Under Port Range enter 8080.

Now try http://<your_public_ip>:8080 (use http:// if https:// doesn't work)